# bad request error when persisting TableEntity

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have a TableEntity like this:

```
public class TableEntity : TableEntity
{
    public string SomeXml { get; set; }
}
```

which contains an XML string called SomeXmL. Most TableEntities persist fine but for some I get:

```
{"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}
```

The XML string of one of the TableEntities producing the exception contains 33933 characters. Is there a limit? Not sure how else to establish the cause of the exception. One sample XML causing the exception can be found [here](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?retmode=xml&db=pubmed&id=26838787).

Comment: What is the HTTP status message? it provides useful information. You can retrieve it from the exception using 'e.RequestInformation.HttpStatusMessage'. Also, what are your partition key and row key?

Comment: Great tip. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because that data you're trying to insert is exceeding the maximum size allowed for an entity attribute. **`The maximum size of an entity attribute is 64KB however because strings in Azure Tables are UTF-16 encoded, maximum size of a String type attribute is 32KB`**.

Because your XML size is more than 32KB, you're getting this error.

When I tried to insert the sample data you shared in a table in my storage account I got the following error back:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "PropertyValueTooLarge",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US", 
            "value": "The property value exceeds the maximum allowed size (64KB). If the property value is a string, it is UTF-16 encoded and the maximum number of characters should be 32K or less.\nRequestId:693f46ec-0002-0012-3a5a-cbcb16000000\nTime:2016-06-21T01:14:00.4544620Z"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I zip this? Or are there other ways to store this?

Comment: Zipping would not help IMHO as you don't know the size of XML file. One alternative would be to save this XML file in blob storage (where each blob can be up to 200GB in size) and save the blob URL in table. HTH.

Comment: Yeah blob storage sounds good. Bit surprised about the limitations of table storage.